# Редактор массивов

Tags: c++, c, windows

Мне нужно сделать редактор массивов, т.е. в терминал выводится массив и с помощью стрелочек можно поменять значения и сохранить, не могу понять, как это сделать. Есть идея вывести массив в input и там уже менять и сохранять массив, как новый, а предудыщий удалять, но не знаю инстрементов, которые умеют так делать.

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял, то вам нужен curses

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Идея хорошая, спасибо, если создадите ответ, помечу правильным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для создание интерфейса программы в терминале отлично подойдёт `curses` (`ncurses`, `pdcurses`).